How do I manually add a custom x-session-manager option for Ubuntu 20.04?
I am trying to set up a single program to run (qemu-system-x86_64) by selecting it as a window manager on the login screen and then logging in. I have created a .desktop file in /usr/share/xsession that runs a bash script that exec's the app, and I can select that option, login, and the application launches. When I exit qemu I am returned to the login screen. It works great but the app does not run full screen, even when given the -full-screen option.
My question is, what do I need to put in that file to get the app to run in full screen mode? I'm guessing it involves running a window manager, A) I don't need all the fluff of a windows manager and B) I would like to configure everything in the bash file.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

After some googling, trial, and error, I figured it out. The bash script should look something like this:
#!/bin/bash
xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
exec /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -blah -blah -blah

It works beautifully. I log in at the windows prompt, qemu displays full screen, and when I exit qemu I am returned to the login screen.
